# Dropzone.js - nothing happens when click dropzone element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm trying add [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com) component in a page and I'm having such a big pain with this component: no matter what I do, nothing happens when I click or drop file in the dropzone's element.

```
<form id="registerUserForm" onsubmit="return submitForm()" class="mt-5">

    <div id="dropzoneDiv" class="dropzone dz-clickable">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message">
            <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
        </div>
     </div>
        .
        .
        .
</form>
```

As you can see, I'm configuring Dropzone in javascript:

```
var dropzone=null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    dropzone=$("#dropzoneDiv").dropzone({
        url: "/api/works/upload",
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*,video/*',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        createImageThumbnails: true,
        addRemoveLinks: true
    });
});

function submitForm() {
    dropzone.processQueue();
    return false;
}
```

The component is correctly rendered, however simple does not work:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong I didn't notice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by chance, the problem is with $(document).ready() sentence. If I remove this listener and use the dropzone configuration call directly, the component works correctly:

```
var dropzone = null;

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
dropzone = $("#dropzoneDiv").dropzone({
    url: "/api/works/upload",
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*,video/*',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    createImageThumbnails: true,
    addRemoveLinks: true
});

function submitForm() {
    dropzone.processQueue();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **JQuery** 2.*, 
If you are using **JQuery** > 3

```js
var dropzone=null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    dropzone=$("#dropzoneDiv").dropzone({
        url: "/api/works/upload",
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*,video/*',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        createImageThumbnails: true,
        addRemoveLinks: true
    });
});

function submitForm() {
    dropzone.processQueue();
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<form id="registerUserForm" onsubmit="return submitForm()" class="mt-5">

    <div id="dropzoneDiv" class="dropzone dz-clickable">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message">
            <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```